# Auto layout with custom UITableViewCell without storyboard programmatically (Swift 5)

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am having some difficulty with Auto Layout within the confines of a UITableViewCell. I am fairly new to Swift so any help would be appreciated. I am trying to create a custom cell where the cell contains three UIImageView objects arranged as shown.

```
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
  +----------------------------------+   +-----------------------------------+
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |               view2               |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   +-----------------------------------+
  |               view1              |
  |                                  |   +-----------------------------------+
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |               view3               |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  +----------------------------------+   +-----------------------------------+
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```

But what I'm actually getting is the following where view1, view2, and view3 are properly aligned but they are not anchored to the contentView of the cell on the bottom and since it is a resizable cell and nothing is pinned to the bottom it ignores the content and fixes itself to the estimated 44 high estimated cell height.

```
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
  +----------------------------------+   +-----------------------------------+
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
  |                                  |   |               view2               |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
  |                                  |   +-----------------------------------+
  |               view1              |
  |                                  |   +-----------------------------------+
  |                                  |   |                                   |
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |               view3               |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  |                                  |   |                                   |
  +----------------------------------+   +-----------------------------------+
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```

The code below includes a .anchor method as a UIView extension for handling anchors more efficiently but otherwise you get the point.

```
import UIKit

class GalleryTableCell: UITableViewCell, SelfConfiguringCell {

    lazy var view1: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    lazy var view2: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    lazy var view3: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    static var identifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupCellView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupCellView() {
        backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        [view1, view2, view3].forEach { ( addSubview($0) ) }

        view1.anchor(top: topAnchor, bottom: nil, leading: nil, trailing: trailingAnchor, with: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 6), size: CGSize(width: 175, height: 0))

        view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        view2.anchor(top: view1.bottomAnchor, bottom: nil, leading: nil, trailing: view1.trailingAnchor, with: UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
        view2.resize(to: view1)

        view3.anchor(top: topAnchor, bottom: view2.bottomAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, trailing: view1.leadingAnchor, with: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 6))

    }

    func configure(with app: Any) {}

}
```

Because I'm using auto dimension to auto-size the cell the above line is required to constrain the view into the cell, otherwise the cell will size to the estimated height (44) and the three views will extend covering over a number of cells below it.

Help understanding what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you’re setting the `heightAnchor` of the cell to the height of `view3`, which should be half the height.

Comment: Thanks for your response @nighttalker but that was leftover code that I accidentally copied in.  I have refreshed the question with some edits to make it clearer and correct.

Comment: Are you implementing `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: Yes. On initialization... tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension and tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension. But no fixed values. I'm trying to understand why the UIViews created in the cell, sized, and placed do not allow the cell to figure out what the autoDimension is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get automatic sizing, you need to do 3 things:

1. Set `estimatedRowHeight` to whatever you think the size will be. It doesn't have to be exact, but it helps with performance.
2. Set `rowHeight` to `UITableView.automaticDimension`.
3. Set `top` & `bottom` constraints of the `view` as well as a `height` constraint.

Comment: I'm going to give you the solution here because it made me think as to what I was doing wrong. I was trying to set the height constraints but I was using equalToConstant instead of greaterThanOrEqualToConstant.

Comment: Are you sure that setting a height constraint solved that for you @nighttalker ? It doesn't make sense because we want the cell to auto grow and setting a constant height prevent it from doing it...